# Need a Linq Query for Corresponding Sql Query

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework-4

Basicall I have three Tables Users Roles and USerRoles with Many to many Relationship. So when I import these on .edmx i get only two Entities. so i have Navigation Properties in both Entities.
I have three Users and 2 Roles (admin and ReadOnly). So 
Now I want to fetch all USers who has admin role.
Below is my Sql Query

```
select U.UserName from Users U
Inner Join UserRoles UR on U.UseID = UR.UserId where UR.RoleId = 1
```

I want above in Linq query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
users.Include("Roles").Where(u => u.Roles.Any(x => x.Id == 1))
```

Comment: Hi I don have UserRoles Entity in my DbContext. So i cant join the way u did. So how to achieve this?..

Comment: Do you have the Roles entity? in your context?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**

```
var result = Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Any(x => x.RoleId == 1))
```

Comment: Hi I don have UserRoles Entity in my DbContext. So i cant join the way u did. So how to achieve this?..

Comment: So if you have Roles under Users entity in your context, try updated solution from above. LINQ expression will be translated to correct SQL using you many-to-many relation.